# Getting value counts from dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe. Here `Name` represents the name of the badge and `Class` represents the level of the badge `(1=Gold, 2=Silver, 3=Bronze)`. I want to get the users in the following three categories:

1. Users having gold medals (may or may not have silver and bronze)
2. Users having silver medals but not gold (may or may not have bronze)
3. Users having only bronze medals and none of silver or gold.

I have written the code but I don't think it is right. Please provide me a way to do this.

**DataFrame**

```
   Id | UserId |  Name          |        Date              |Class | TagBased
   2  | 23     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   3  | 22     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   4  | 21     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   5  | 20     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   6  | 19     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
```

**Code**

```
df_gold_users = badges[(badges['Class'] == '1')]
df_silver_users = badges[(badges['Class'] != '1') & (badges['Class'] != '3')]
df_bronze_users = badges[(badges['Class'] != '1') & (badges['Class'] != '2')]

gold_users = df_gold_users['UserId'].value_counts().index
silver_users = df_silver_users['UserId'].value_counts().index
bronze_users = df_bronze_users['UserId'].value_counts().index
```

Comment: Why don't you think it is correct?

Comment: Because the UserId column does not have unique user values, the values are repeated based on the number of earned badges. In the 2nd line of code I have mentioned not to include class 1 user, but pick up class 2 user, but it may so happen that the user is common to both classes 1 and 2. Thus, even if I pick the class 2 user I am automatically picking a class 1 user.

Comment: Can't you add this is second line:
`(badges['Class'] != '1') & (badges['Class'] == '2')` - Users not having Gold, but Silver.

Comment: Yeah this would do, thanks a lot. Should I also include (badges['Class'] !='3') in the 2nd line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Define conditions as tuples:

```
gold_only=(1,)
gold_and_silver=(1,2)
gold_silver_bronze=(1,2,3)
gold_and_bronze=(1,3)
silver_only=(2,)
silver_and_bronze=(2,3)
bronze_only=(3,)
```

Use `groupby` and `tuple`:

```
   df_grouped=df.groupby('Userid')['Class'].unique().apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).reset_index()
```

Perform the tests:

```
df_grouped['Gold_users']=(df_grouped['Class']==(gold_only))|(df_grouped['Class']==(gold_and_silver))|(df_grouped['Class']==(gold_silver_bronze))|(df_grouped['Class']==(gold_and_bronze))
df_grouped['Silver_users']=(df_grouped['Class']==(silver_only))|(df_grouped['Class']==(silver_and_bronze))
df_grouped['Bronze_users']=(df_grouped['Class']==(bronze_only))
```